# IIS AppPool is getting auto-stopped

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2012

I am deploying ASP.NET Core Web applications on IIS server. Its working fine on my local environment. But When deployed on Windows server machine, app pools are getting auto-stopped with identity type- **ApplicationPoolIdentity**. After changing identity type to **LocalSystem**, its started working fine..
So my question is: why its not working with **ApplicationPoolIdentity**?

Comment: check the logs.

Comment: event log: Application pool 'xx' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Comment: Sounds like your application requires permissions that you have not assigned to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. You're going to have to figure out what it's trying to do that it can't.

Comment: I am trying to figure out.. can you guide what things to investigate/

Comment: I suggest you could firstly open the event viewer's application or system logs to see why it returned the error and then according to the error message we could know what happened. Normally, this issue is related with the permission.

Comment: Application Log: 
There was an error during processing of the managed application service auto-start for configuration path: 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/xxx/'. The error message returned is: ''.  The worker process will be marked unhealthy and be shutdown.  The data field contains the error code.

System Log:
Application pool 'xx' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Comment: Another logs inside the system? This just show some error when running the application. Like WAS or else.